# How to use a config file with React Tools

Tags: reactjs

The [React Tools](https://www.npmjs.org/package/react-tools) documentation mentions a command line flag (-c, --config) that can be used to specify a JSON configuration file for transforming JSX files to vanilla JS.  What I am not sure of is what can be specified with this config file and what it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The JSX tool uses [commoner](https://github.com/reactjs/commoner#configuration) under the hood. But afaik that option isn't officially used.